# An easier solution to Euclid's Book I, Proposition 5?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[Proposition 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrwNc.gif)

Does not Common Notion 3 (If equals are subtracted from equals the remainders are equal) solve Proposition 5 all on its own?

1. Lines AB and AC are equal.
2. The base angles ABC and ACB are equal.
3. Extending lines AB and AC, and plotting points F and G gives us equal lines AF and AG.

Does it not follow that angles FBC and GCB are the remainders and therefore equal?

Comment: Point 2. must be proved, it is not given.

Comment: Moreover, read the "Guide" here: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI5.html

Comment: Better, point 2 is what one is _trying_ to prove, so it's circular.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. Thanks for the link.
So Definition 20 doesn't prove point 2 in that it defines an isosceles triangle: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/defI20.html

Comment: @Squinter Definition $20$ defines an equilateral triangle as one of which two *sides* are equal. The fact that the two *angles* opposite those sides are also equal needs to be *proved*, and  Proposition $5$ is the one that proves it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. All that helped.